# Implementing the De Boor splining algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, .net, math, interpolation, polynomial-math

I know it's a slightly "Please do my homework" question, but I'm trying to implement the De Boor algorithm as explained here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Boor's_algorithm

I have got a generic class which takes any array of any type and two functions which yield an x and y for each point.

I am getting very inaccurate interpolations when I supply to GetPoint(x) an x which is very near to the lowest x value in _d.

Is anyone able to see what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks in advance.

The data I'm using are:

```
x           y
0.002739726 0.999988548
0.019178082 0.999917365
0.038356164 0.999835128
0.057534247 0.999753381
0.082191781 0.999648832
0.167123288 0.999286638
0.249315068 0.998939303
0.334246575 0.998583164
0.419178082 0.998222171
0.495890411 0.997899634
0.747945205 0.99680615
1           0.99559971
1.249315068 0.994187653
1.495890411 0.9926708
1.747945205 0.99066351
2           0.988439344
2.249315068 0.985377424
2.498630137 0.981972695
2.750684932 0.978188863
3.002739726 0.974069647
4.002739726 0.952415995
5.002739726 0.926226504
6.002739726 0.897271422
7.005479452 0.866241091
8.005479452 0.834348616
9.005479452 0.802369725
```

The code

```
public class Spline<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Coordinate
    /// </summary>
    private struct TwoDPoint
    {
        public double x;
        public double y;
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Unused apart from debugging.
    /// </summary>
    private T [] _originalDataPoints;

    /// <summary>
    /// Stores the points we will perform the algorithm on.
    /// </summary>      
    private TwoDPoint [] _d;        
    private int _n; // Value for the "order" used in the De Boor algorithm

    public Spline(T [] dataPoints, Func<T, double> xFunc, Func<T, double> yFunc, int n)
    {           
        SortAndAssignPoints(dataPoints, xFunc, yFunc);
        _n = n;         
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Populates points in d sorted ascending by their x value
    /// </summary>
    private void SortAndAssignPoints(T [] dataPoints, Func<T, double> xFunc, Func<T, double> yFunc)
    {
        _originalDataPoints = dataPoints;

        _d = dataPoints
            .Select(point => new TwoDPoint()
                        {
                            x = xFunc(point),
                            y = yFunc(point)
                        })
            .OrderBy(point => point.x).ToArray();
    }   

    /// <summary>
    /// Function which gets an interpolated value
    /// </summary>
    public double GetPoint(double x)
    {
        double sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < _d.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += _d[i].y * N_General(_n, i, x);
        }

        return sum;         
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// General N function as given in the algorithm
    /// </summary>
    private double N_General(int n, int i, double x)
    {
        if (n == 0)
        {
            return N_Base(i, x);
        }

        double firstCoefficient;

        if ((i + n) > (_d.Length - 1))
        {
            firstCoefficient = 0D;
        }
        else
        {
            firstCoefficient =
                (x - _d[i].x) / (_d[i + n].x - _d[i].x);                
        }

        double secondCoefficient;

        if ((i + n + 1) > (_d.Length - 1))
        {
            secondCoefficient = 0D;
        }
        else
        {
            secondCoefficient = 
                (_d[i + n + 1].x - x) / (_d[i + n + 1].x - _d[i + 1].x);                
        }


        return firstCoefficient * N_General(n - 1, i, x) +
            secondCoefficient * N_General(n - 1, i + 1, x);
    }       

    /// <summary>
    /// N_i^0 as given in the algorithm
    /// </summary>
    private double N_Base(int i, double x)
    {
        //Bound check
        if (
            (i >= (_d.Length - 1)) ||
            (i < 0)
        )
        {
            return 0;
        }           

        if ((x >= _d[i].x) &&
            (x < _d[i+1].x))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944532/implementing-de-boors-algorithm-for-finding-points-on-a-b-spline but I'm struggling to map this example to my own. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Groo! Appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your codes, it looks like you are using y values from _d as the control points and x values from _d as the knot values. Please note that for B-spline curves the control points in general do not lie on the curve itself. So, you should not expect that passing an x value from your data array to GetPoint(x) function will get back the corresponding y value in the data array.

Also, for B-spline curves, the rule of "number of knots = number of control points + order" should always be followed. You really cannot use_d[i].x as knots and _d[i].y as control points as you will have the same number of knots and control points.

Finally, I would recommend using [this](http://cse.taylor.edu/~btoll/s99/424/res/ucdavis/CAGDNotes/Deboor-Cox-Calculation/Deboor-Cox-Calculation.html) as your reference instead of the Wikipedia link as it offers better description of De Boor-Cox algorithm.

Comment: Sorry for the late response - but thanks for that link!